# Proper validation of time intervals within the same day

Tags: java, date, jodatime, localdate

I have a method as follows:

```
public void storeAppointment(int year,
    int monthOfYear,
    int dayOfMonth,
    int hourOfDayFrom,
    int minuteFrom,
    int hourOfDayUntil, int minuteUntil) {

    Calendar appointmentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    appointmentCalendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    TimeZone tz = appointmentCalendar.getTimeZone();
    DateTimeZone jodaTz = DateTimeZone.forID(tz.getID());
    DateTime appointmentDateTime = new DateTime(appointmentCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), jodaTz);
    LocalDate localDate = appointmentDateTime.toLocalDate();

    // At this point I have the appointment date.  

    // Should e.g. throw an exception for invalid time interval
    validate(hourOfDayFrom, minuteFrom, hourOfDayUntil, minuteUntil);

    // set proper times for calendar
    appointmentCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourOfDay);
    appointmentCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    // store date and times  
    // Should I update the localDate instead of the appointmentCalendar?
}
```

**Questions:**

1. How should I validate the hours/minutes? Should the actual date be included or is that not relevant?
2. Should I update the `localDate` instead of the `appointmentCalendar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working much too hard here.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Avoid using the troublesome old date-time classes, such as `Date` & `Calendar`. Now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Do not mix date-time libraries

Do not mix the different date-time libraries. If using Joda-Time, no need for `java.util.Date` and no need for `java.util.Calendar`. And if using java.time classes, no need for Joda-Time and no need for `java.util.Date`/`.Calendar`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

## Business rules

> Should the actual date be included or is that not relevant?

We cannot tell you whether to consider the date or not. That depends on your business rules.

For example, if your business always takes a lunch break from noon to 13:00, then any business record marked with a time-of-day in that hour must be invalid. Date is irrelevant here if you always take the same lunch break every single day.

But if your scenario is something like recording a worker’s periods worked, then no two periods should overlap *on the same day*. In this case you must consider the date.

## `ZonedDateTime`

> Should I update the localDate instead of the appointmentCalendar?

a) You should not be mixing these classes, as discussed above.

b) In both Joda-Time and java.time, the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day. And like its sibling `Local…` classes, it purposely has no concept of time zone. So not at all a fit for your purpose.

You need to use `ZonedDateTime` to represent a date and a time-of-day that has meaning within your intended time zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 23 );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 30 );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );
```

To get the current moment:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();  // UTC.
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

…or, as a shortcut…

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

Also, the java.time classes are [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So you do not change (“mutate”) their values. Instead you instantiate a new object based on the original’s values.

## Interval

You may find the [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class in [ThreeTen-Extras](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project to be helpful here.

```
Interval a = Interval.of( zdtStart.toInstant() , zdtStop.toInstant() );
```

You can compare intervals with methods such as `contains`, `overlaps`, `encloses`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter`.

```
Boolean overlaps = a.overlaps( b );
```

## Pass around objects

Rather than pass around mere primitives of piecemeal data, pass objects.

So instead of passing primitives such as integers for month, date, and hour, pass java.time objects such as `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`. When you have only the date or only the time-of-day, pass `LocalDate` or `LocalTime`.

## Default time zone

To get the JVM’s current default time zone, call [`ZoneId.systemDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--).

But if important you should be asking the user for their desired/expected time zone. That default can change at any moment by any code in any thread of any app running in that JVM.

Comment: Very helpful indeed! You are "hardcoding" a specific timezone while I tried to be generic via `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone()`. How can I replace this so that I remove Calendar completely?

Comment: @Jim See last section added about default time zone.